# 3-phase unbalanced power supply

Tags: power, ac, three-phase

I have a 3-phase power supply with 115 V phase. I am giving 2 of it phases to AC-DC converter with DC side having 50 W of load. The 3rd phase is no load. There is no neutral connection required for my circuit. I am getting different power factors for 2 phases and the other one as 1 being no load. My question is, shouldn't the power factors be same for both the phases which I am using as they are only given to converter?

Comment: It would be useful to see a diagram of your setup, details of how you are measuring the power factors, and the specific reading you are getting.  There are several possible explanations, but it is hard to give the correct one without more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to make some assumptions in this answer

1. You have a system with 120V from phase to neutral and 208V from phase to phase.
2. even though your load is not connected to neutral, you measured power factor in each phase with relation to ground or neutral (for the purposes of this question ground and neutral can be considered equivalent).

> My question is, shouldn't the power factors be same for both the phases which I am using as they are only given to converter?

Lets imagine you have a resistive load that draws 1A at 208V connected between phases. So our resistor has a voltage of 208V and a current of 1A for a total of 208VA. However 120V * 1A * 2 is 240VA.

So that leads to the question, where did the other 22VA go?

The answer is that while the voltage and current in the load are in-phases, the voltage between either phase and neutral is not in phase with the voltage through the load.

In an ideal system, with a resistive load, there will be a phase offset of 30 degrees between the phase to neutral voltage, and the phase to phase current. The power factor encountered on the two phases would be the same numerically, but it's associated phase angle would be opposite. On one phase it would be "leading" while on the other it would be "lagging".

---

That is all assuming ideal conditions though, there are a couple of things that could cause the measured power factor on different phases to be different.

Firstly, unless your power supply has fancy active power factor correction, it is likely to have a power factor significantly less than 1. This reduced power factor represents a combination of phase offset and harmonics.

The harmonics will affect both phases equally. However the phase offset will affect the two phases differently. On one phase, the phase offset from the phase to phase connection and the phase offset from the load will be in the same direction and will add together, while on the other phase they will be in opposite directions and will (partially) cancel. So if the load has a phase offset then the power factor measured on the two phases will be different.

Also the supply itself may have different voltages on different phases due to unbalanced loading. If so then the angles formed by the phase to phase connection will be different.

Comment: I got my answer as well. I will just add here which is on the same line as yours. Since there is no neutral connection on load side, the power factor being shown on power supply will not be the right one which i want to get. As i am supplying L-L to the converter and getting power factor for L-N will not be equivalent. coming to the next part where both phases should show same numerical value but opposite in phases, this is where your phase offset solution helped me. Thanks a lot 